# Scala: Value Class vs Case Class

Tags: scala, case-class, value-class

I'm trying to discover the differences between using a value class or a case class in a given scenario.  Suppose I want to model the integers mod 5 as a unique datatype.  The question is which one I should begin with...

```
class IntegerMod5(val value: Int) extends AnyVal
case class IntegerMod5(value: Int)
```

Regardless, it seems that I can create an implementation of `Numeric` fairly easily.  With the case class approach, then, I can simply do this:

```
case class IntegerMod5(value: Int)(implicit ev: Numeric[IntegerMod5]) {
    import ev.mkNumericOps
}
```

However, it seems to be a much more difficult endeavour with value classes, mainly as the benefit is to avoid object creation.  Thus, something like

```
implicit class IntegersMod5Ops(value: IntegerMod5)(implicit ev: Numeric[IntegerMod5]) {
    import ev.mkNumericOps
}
```

Would appear to largely defeat the purpose.  (Not sure if it even works, actually.)

The question is that is it possible to use `Numeric` with a value class, or will I have to bite the bullet and use a case class?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `implicit ev: Numeric[IntegerMod5]` as an argument, just define it in the companion object:

```
object IntegerMod5 {
  implicit val numeric: Numeric[IntegerMod5] = ...
}
```

It will be automatically picked up when you use arithmetic operations on `IntegerMod5`s, and because it's a `val`, it's only initialized once (you can use `object` as well).